# Python Pandas Drop from Table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to delete some rows from the table to show them on the graph.
I want to delete all rows that have no position 1, to only count the teams that have won.
My code look like this: (cons is the name of original table)

```
gry=cons
team_win = gry.drop(gry[gry.Position != '1'].index)

team_win_c= gry.groupby('Team')['Team'].count()
team_win_c = pd.DataFrame(team_win_c)
team_win_c.columns = ['Wins']
team_win_c.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

team_win_c.sort_values(by=['Wins'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
team_win_c = team_win_c.head(10)
team_win_c = team_win_c[::-1]

fig = px.bar(team_win_c, x='Team', y='Wins',color='Wins',width=750, height=500)
fig.update_layout(title={'text': 'Teams with The Most Championships Won','y':0.95,'x':0.5})
fig.show()
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PONt3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try first find string `?` in columns, create boolean mask and last filter rows - use boolean indexing. If you need convert columns to float, use astype:

```
print ~((df['X'] == '?' )  (df['Y'] == '?' ) | (df['Z'] == '?' ))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool

df1 = df[~((df['X'] == '?' ) | (df['Y'] == '?' ) | (df['Z'] == '?' ))].astype(float)
print df1
   X  Y  Z
1  1  2  3
3  4  4  4

print df1.dtypes
X    float64
Y    float64
Z    float64
dtype: object
```

**Or you can try:**

```
df['X'] = pd.to_numeric(df['X'], errors='coerce')
df['Y'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Y'], errors='coerce')
df['Z'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Z'], errors='coerce')
print df
    X   Y   Z
0   0   1 NaN
1   1   2   3
2 NaN NaN   4
3   4   4   4
4 NaN   2   5
print ((df['X'].notnull() ) & (df['Y'].notnull() ) & (df['Z'].notnull() ))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool

print df[ ((df['X'].notnull() ) & (df['Y'].notnull() ) & (df['Z'].notnull() )) ].astype(float)
   X  Y  Z
1  1  2  3
3  4  4  4
```

Better is to  use:

```
df = df[(df != '?').all(axis=1)]
```

Or:

```
df = df[~(df == '?').any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Oh thanks man, I am just a beginner and have another stupid question, so to do this kind of filters i need to always change the data type first right?

Comment: Yes, also you need to enter the rewas companion on the 8th port in order to simulate the python matrices. This is pretty basic stuff, you should be able to understand it.